# Phantom Cassandra batch insert

Tags: phantom-dsl

Is there batch insert API in phantom-dsl to batch insert to cassandra?
Tried searching but could not find it in the code.

Also i could not find enough documentation on the phantom library.

Comment: https://github.com/websudos/phantom/wiki/Batch-statements

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for batch inserts to optimize performance, you are doing it wrong!

For further information, please refer to:
https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e

Anyway, phantom supports batch-statements as @flavian commented
https://github.com/websudos/phantom/wiki/Batch-statements

Also, check out my github project that shows how to implement things in phantom-dsl.

[https://github.com/iamthiago/cassandra-phantom](https://github.com/thiagoandrade6/cassandra-phantom)